# Snowflake tasks are not triggered by schedule since 13h UTC the 16th of march

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm facing an issue with my snowflake instance.

No tasks are running anymore. This suddenly happened.

I can run my tasks manually, but the automatic schedule is not triggering anything since 13 UTC today.

Do you have the same behavior ?

Thanks all

**EDIT:**

I have two tasks that are scheduled the same way (several times in a day), same schema, same user. One ran until 1h14 AM the other one ran all day long (as expected)

**SOLUTION :**
The only fix that I found was to recreate the task by doing and to make it run normally again.

To do so :

```
select get_ddl('task', 'TASK_NAME')
```

Execute the code provided by the query

Resume the task :

```
Alter task TASK_NAME RESUME
```

Comment: Is your account located in AWS US-EAST? There was an [incident](https://status.snowflake.com/incidents/jj1vgwvgxdqj) today that should be resolved now.

Comment: Yes I am. I think you talk about this  https://status.snowflake.com/incidents/jj1vgwvgxdqj which is not about tasks imo It says " A subset of customers hosted in the specified regions may have experienced delays while attempting to execute queries. Affected customers may have encountered query failures." Even if it is resolved, tasks are still not running.

Comment: Then I would suggest to open a case with support as someone from Snowflake needs to look further into this.

Comment: What does the task history show for when the tasks last ran and are next scheduled to run?

Comment: Nothing, like it is not executed at all. I haven't identified the pattern yet but some are running, and some not. No changes has been done to the tasks.

Comment: There can’t be nothing. Presumably it is showing instances of the task that previously succeeded? Is the latest instance for each task the last one to succeed, a scheduled one with the scheduled time in the past, a scheduled one scheduled in the future, or an errored instance?

Comment: @StevensLaurent The issue should have been resolved and it seems it is related to the incident from yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was actually something, some of my tasks didn't resumed themselves after the snowplow bug fix : status.snowflake.com/incidents/jj1vgwvgxdqj

The only fix that I found was to recreate the task by doing and to make it run normally again.

To do so :

```
select get_ddl('task', 'TASK_NAME')
```

Execute the code provided by the query

Resume the task :

```
Alter task TASK_NAME RESUME
```

Thank you all for your help